# Laravel 5 Data Objects through lifecycle

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5, data-objects

The present control flow, when I register a new user on my Laravel 5 app, the way the request lifecycle is handled is:

- **RegisterRequest** calls the validator to pass through after validation >
- (**RegisterRequest** obj) MyAuthController >
- dispatches (**User** obj) RegisterUserCommand >
- maps fields to **RegisterUserCommand** object >
- handler called at (**RegisterUserCommand** obj) RegisterUserCommandHandler >
- creates new user by creating a **User** obj >
- then calling **$user->save()**
- which saves it to the database

Am I doing it right? Is it right to pass data this way? 
User model is invoked and mapped to twice, is this good practice?

Specification: Laravel framework v5.0.28 with MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean when you say

`maps fields to RegisterUserCommand object >`

However here is how the life cycle should roughly be

1. Routes.php dispaches route to UserController.php
2. postRegisterUser() method is called
3. A new User model object is instantiated
4. All of the properties are assigned to the new User objects's instance
   attributes.
5. The User model object's save() method is called and the
   database is updated

Comment: you are talking basic record insertion in database through laravel. the framework offers other features like command bus, event dispatchers, etc which need data objects to be passed through several classes. the answer is irrelevant to what i asked. please see what i've asked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to save or process any request

1. Synchronous
2. Asynchronous

When you execute something synchronously, you wait for it to finish before moving on to another task. When you execute something asynchronously, you can move on to another task before it finishes.

I think from your example you are trying to save data in asynchronous way. You can also use laravel Queue to save user in the background. That will save some response time.